# Did I lose my data on switching to another branch git?

Tags: git, github

There are 10 branches in my git. I was working on `develop` branch and did big changes in 3-4 files. After some time I was advised by our team lead that I should switch to another branch (`feature/heavy_calculations`) to test a new feature.

I switched to that branch just by running a command `git checkout feature/heavy_calculations`
But now I lost my code on feature/heavy_calculations. git status is showing

```
# On branch feature/heavy_calculations
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Then I switched back to develop

```
git checkout develop
```

Here as well I am seeing same :

```
# On branch develop
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Did I lose all my data?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't run `git reset --hard` or `git stash` command at all ?

Comment: @blunderboy Thanks, I had run the git stash. but I forgot that after switching the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have accepted that you have run `git stash` to stash the changes So the answer is **NO You have not lost the changes**. You can still get them back by running:

```
git stash apply
```

or

```
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have, but just running `git checkgout <branchname>` does not touch locally modified files.
Maybe you're on the wrong local git or something like that?

Comment: I had run `git stash`, Thanks for the reply